# Filming location in “The Woman Who Fell to Earth”

Tags: doctor-who, real-location

The bike riding scenes from the new episode of *Doctor Who* were – I assume – set somewhere in the Peak District, fairly close by to Sheffield.

[image: The Doctor looking at the scenery]

Does anyone know where exactly these scenes were filmed?

Comment: I'm reasonably convinced that it's near Oughtibridge but I'm guessing they're jumping around in order to get good shots.

Comment: Exactly? No. Rough idea? Yes. _"The Woman Who Fell to Earth was shot on location in Cardiff and Sheffield (where the episode is set), and also in the production facilities at Roath Lock Studios."_ - [RadioTimes](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/tv/2018-10-07/doctor-who-series-11-behind-the-scenes-jodie-whittaker-filming-location-guide-theme-music-soundtrack-bbc/). _"The cinematography of the Peaks around Sheffield here is gorgeous"_ - [RadioTimes](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/tv/2018-10-07/doctor-who-series-11-episode-1-as-it-happens/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Near Halifax, or Cardiff, possibly both

As TheLethalCarrot points out in a comment, [*Radio Times*](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/tv/2018-10-07/doctor-who-series-11-behind-the-scenes-jodie-whittaker-filming-location-guide-theme-music-soundtrack-bbc/) says that the episode was filmed in Cardiff and Sheffield.

A blog called [*A Geek in Time and Space*](http://www.mygeekytravels.com/sheffield-the-woman-who-fell-to-earth/) identifies several of the Sheffield locations. One of the comments on the blog links to [a tweet](https://twitter.com/markham431/status/1051032638700564480) from Terry Markham identifying the location of the opening scene as being near Halifax (a little northwest of Sheffield).

> The opening scene with the hills and valley looked very much like Halifax/Elland to me looking down across the valley towards Ainley Top / M62. The road looked very much like the A629 but was trying to place it myself

The blogger agrees with the comment and notes that the opening scene includes a brief shot of the nearby Emley Moor TV transmitter.

[image]

The red marker in the following shows the location of the transmitter. Halifax is at the top left and Elland is centre left.

[image]

A second comment on the blog identifies the place where Ryan throws his bike as being near Cardiff.

> I was hoping that the scene where Ryan throws his bike off the cliff was also in the peak district, but alas it is just outside Cardiff. Here to be exact.
>
> https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.5433958,-3.2812334,709a,35y,90h,39.25t/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en
>
> If you look at the map, and compare to the scene, you can see the tennis courts and the industrial estate in the background (also someone on Reddit helped me). I’ll have to save that for my next trip to Cardiff.
>
> I spent hours (literally) looking at the map of the peak district trying to find those tennis courts.

[image]

Comment: "I spent hours (literally) looking at the map of the peak district trying to find those tennis courts." LOL I can sympathise with that fellow, as I've been geotagging 20 year old holiday photos recently using vague memories and Google StreetView as my guide! Thanks for the well-researched answer.